# How to write Hanief (my name) in Japanese?

Tags: katakana, names

I'm Indonesian and am still learning Japanese. I'm curious how to write my name Hanief (Haniif or usually just Hanif).

It's from the Arabic word (حنيف) and means

1. righteous
2. upright or true believer

Is this katakana right?

- ハニーフ
- ハニエフ

Comment: This guy with the same first name has it as ハニフ: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%8B%E3%83%95%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B7

Comment: Other than liberal arts, there's wikipedia page for [ムハンマド・**ハニーフ**・アトマル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A0%E3%83%8F%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%89%E3%83%BB%E3%83%8F%E3%83%8B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%88%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB)  (パシュトー語: محمد حنيف اتمر、英: [Mohammad Hanif Atmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Hanif_Atmar)), the former Interior Minister of Afghanistan. So, also「ハニーフ」 should be one of the candidate of حنيف

Answer (score 8):

I think that either ハニーフ or ハニフ is probably what you want.

As has been mentioned in the comments, both seem to be used by people with the same name. I think the best way to choose between the two is to use the pronunciation/intonation in your native language as a guide:

- if you pronounce your name as ***Ha***nif (i.e. the stress on the first syllable / short *i*), you might want to go for ハニフ
- if you pronounce it *Han**i**f* (i.e. stress on the second syllable / long *i*), you might want to go for ハニーフ.

(The reason is that the natural pitch accent will be ハニフ【HLL】 and ハニーフ【LHLL】 and one of those would be a better match for the intonation in your language.)

Comment: I agree Arabic words and names tend to be either the two and not エル for some reason where European names would go for エル. not sure why.

Comment: @Saifis Do you mean names like Gabriel or Daniel? Here I and E are pronounced separately and not like a long I, as seems to be the case for Hanief = Haniif.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant エフ, I meant that in scenarios that you could have an エ in there middle eastern words and names seem to usually be streched with a ー or not there at all, thus it turning in to ハニーフ or ハニフ. of course this is just my observation as a Japanese and not like I have academic understandings of it.